# Create fullchain, cert.pem and chain.pem from ca_bundle.crt

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a ca_bundle.crt, certificate.crt, private.key but I need to create the following pem files out of the files.

```
fullchain.pem
chain.pem
cert.pem
```

Any suggestion on how to create those files?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need it separated?

Comment: The configuration files needs all three as a separated files. Lets encrypt provides them separately but zerossl provides only ca_bundle.crt and private.key

Comment: What are fullchain.pem, chain.pem and cert.pem supposed to contain?

Comment: @user what are trying to solve? [X-AND-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)